# How to unmarshal non-trivial mongo return bson struct

Tags: mongodb, go, unmarshalling, bson

The return of mongo is like:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "InternetGatewayDevice": {
            "WANDevice": {
                "1": {
                    "_instance": true,
                    "_writable": false
                },
                "2": {
                    "_instance": true,
                    "_writable": false
                },
                ...
                "_object": true,
                "_timestamp": {
                    "$date": "2020-11-23T04:14:13.202Z"
                },
                "_writable": false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

- The `WanDevice.1` and `WanDevice.2` is not fixed. Can be `n` objects.
- When the return is a json string the `UnmarshalJSON` works. Because the `id` of `WanDevice.[id]` is sequencial and not repeat, thus I can create a array of `WanDevices` into `InternetGatewayDevice` struct

Can be a way to "unmarshal" this return from mongo without need to create a struct like this?

```golang
type Device struct {
    InternetGatewayDevice InternetGatewayDevice `json:"InternetGatewayDevice" bson:"InternetGatewayDevice"`
}

type InternetGatewayDevice struct {
    WANDevice WANDevice `json:"WANDevice" bson:"WANDevice"`
}

type WANDevice struct {
    DeviceNum1 `json:"1" bson:"1"`
    DeviceNum1 `json:"2" bson:"2"`
    DeviceNum1 `json:"3" bson:"3"`
    DeviceNum1 `json:"4" bson:"4"`
    .....
}
```

- I call it like this:

```golang
    collection := m.Client.Database(acs.Mongo.Database).Collection("devices")
    filter := bson.D{
        {"InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.2.MACAddress._value", parsedMac},
    }

    response := &models.Device{}
    err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(response)
```

Comment: Why can't you use a simple map?

Comment: unfortunately the return is much more bigger than the example I put here, if I make a map of ```&map[string]interface{}{}``` return then will probably consume more memory no?

Comment: If you're so close to running out of memory that the additional memory used by the map keys takes you over the edge, then I'd say you have much bigger problems to worry about. Use the data type that fits the problem. If you have memory issues, address them directly, through profiling and experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UnmarshalJSON, something like this:
https://play.golang.org/p/FdW064a9RDT

Comment: I tried, but ```decode``` function in mongo ```findOne``` return use the ```bson.UnmarshalWithRegistry``` method, that does not call the custom ```UnmarshalJSON``` function unfortunately